# how to display values from a configuration file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the below posted .ini file and i want to have access to its contents from .py and print the value of the api key

**config.ini**:

```
[API_KEY]
default = 5b3ce3597851110001cf62480ecf8c403567479a87de01df5da651cds
```

please let me know how to fix it

**code**:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('configs.ini')
print(config.sections())
print(config['API_KEY'])
exit()
```

**output**:

```
['API_KEY']
<Section: API_KEY>
```

Comment: `config['API_KEY']['default']` ?

Comment: Sorry. Did not see your comment @arhr. If you post an answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscript after reading the config

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('config.ini')
print(config['API_KEY']['default'])
```

Output

```
'5b3ce3597851110001cf62480ecf8c403567479a87de01df5da651cds'
```

It would be much simpler to store it in a JSON.

JSON configuration example `config.json`

```
{
  "api_key": {
    "default": "XYZ",
    "development": "XYZ",
    "production": "ABC"
  }
}
```

Code

```
import json

with open('config.json', 'r') as cfile:
    data = json.load(cfile)

print(data.get('api_key').get('default'))  # XYZ
```

Comment: do you mean to have a config file in json??would you please provide an example